# How do I find gap in sqlite table?

Tags: sql, sqlite, gaps-and-islands

I have a sqlite table with timestamps in milliseconds as primary key each row should be 1 second or 1000 apart from one another. Sometimes my data recorder goes out and there is no data in the table for that time. How can I find the gaps using a SQL statement?  A cursor based solution is possible I know.

```
table = PVT
TS
1119636081000
1119636082000
1119636083000
1119636084000
1119636085000
------gap------
1119636090000
1119636091000
```

Comment: You can make a table of the deltas between the current row and the previous row and look for values greater than 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work. Assuming the table name is "tstamps",

```
select a.ts
from tstamps a
where not exists
   (select b.ts
    from tstamps b
    where b.ts = a.ts+1000)
and exists
   (select c.ts
    from tstamps c
    where c.ts = a.ts+2000)
```

Another way

```
select a.ts
from tstamps a
where not exists
   (select b.ts
    from tstamps b
    where b.ts = a.ts+1000)
and a.ts <
   (select max(c.ts)
    from tstamps c
   )
```

Using MINUS operator. I am not sure, which of these queries does better performance wise.

```
select ts+1000
from pvt
where ts != (select max(ts) from pvt)
minus
select ts
from pvt
where ts != (select min(ts) from pvt)
```

Comment: The last one using MINUS worked for me, I THINK, except sqlite doesn't have a minus operator so I used except.   I checked a few of them using select ts from pvt where ts between X and Y and I see the gaps. Performance isn't really a concern since I won't be running this query often but it took 9seconds on 1.8 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (Assuming PVT.TS is your Column name):

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE PVT.TS ISNULL;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE PVT.TS IS NULL;
```

If your collector is actually entering a blank entry you might need

```
WHERE PVT.TS = ''
```

or

```
where ifnull(some_column, '') = ''
```

Comment: If there's a gap, no row is created, PVT is the table name and TS is the column.

Comment: Ah, so its not an empty field but a break in the pattern. I assume they dont always increment by 5000 each time?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing SQLite does not support window functions like `LAG(TS) OVER (ORDER BY TS ASC)` nor `LEAD() OVER`, which would easily give you the previous and following `TS` values, respectively.

So, you need to do it yourself:

```
sqlite> .mode col
sqlite> .width 14 14 14
sqlite>    SELECT PVT.TS  AS measurement,
                  prev.TS AS prev,
                  next.TS AS next
             FROM PVT
        LEFT JOIN PVT next ON PVT.TS = (next.TS - 1000)
        LEFT JOIN PVT prev ON PVT.TS = (prev.TS + 1000);
```

This will give you something like this (I used different data, as you'll see):

```
-- measurement        prev            next     
  -------------   -------------   -------------
  1119636081000                   1119636082000   -- gap (no previous at all)
  1119636082000   1119636081000   1119636083000 
  1119636083000   1119636082000   1119636084000 
  1119636084000   1119636083000   1119636085000 
  1119636085000   1119636084000                   -- gap (no next offset 1000)
  1119636088000                   1119636089000   -- gap (no previous offset 1000)
  1119636089000   1119636088000                   -- gap (no next at all)
```

You can always restrict that query to only those records `WHERE prev.TS IS NULL OR next.TS is NULL`, too.

Comment: This query will take far too long on almost 2 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tally table with at least 86400 rows (one per second for a day):

```
create table Tally(n integer primary key not null);
insert into Tally(n) values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
insert into Tally(n) select null from tally n1 , tally n2, tally n3, tally n4, tally n5;
```

Join your PVT table onto the transposed records for the day:

```
select 1119636081000 + tally.n*1000 as Expected, pvt.ts from tally left join pvt on pvt.ts = 1119636081000 + tally.n*1000 where tally.n <= 86400 limit 15;
```

Given a table I populated with your sample data I get this as an output:

```
Expected       TS
-------------  -------------
1119636081000  1119636081000
1119636082000  1119636082000
1119636083000  1119636083000
1119636084000  1119636084000
1119636085000  1119636085000
1119636086000
1119636087000
1119636088000
1119636089000
1119636090000  1119636090000
1119636091000  1119636091000
1119636092000
1119636093000
1119636094000
1119636095000
```

If you then additionally filter where PVT.TS is null, you should get the missing values:

```
select 1119636081000 + tally.n*1000 as Expected, pvt.ts from tally left join pvt on pvt.ts = 1119636081000 + tally.n*1000 where tally.n <= 86400 and PVT.ts is null limit 15;

Expected       TS
-------------  ----------
1119636086000
1119636087000
1119636088000
1119636089000
1119636092000
1119636093000
1119636094000
1119636095000
1119636096000
1119636097000
1119636098000
1119636099000
1119636100000
1119636101000
1119636102000
```

NOTE: I'm using limit 15 to keep myself sane at the console

Comment: You don't actually need to create the tally table. You can "create" it with a temporary view, that is, a recursive CTE like this: `with n as (select 1 x union select x+1 from n where x<50), tally as (select 1119636081000+x*1000 ts from n) select * from tally left join pvt on pvt.ts=tally.ts and pvt.ts is null;` (where 50 and 1119636081000 of course are number you need to adjust to your situation)